# change bash script code to perl

Tags: bash, perl

In bash :

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(cat ps.txt)
for i in $var ; do
echo $i
done
```

and ps.txt is :

```
356735
535687
547568537
7345673
3653468
2376958764
12345678
12345
```

Now I want to do that with perl or i want to know how to save the output of a command in a variable in perl like `var=$(cat ps.txt)`

Comment: `while read i; do echo "$i"; done < ps.txt` is a more correct way to do that in `bash`.

Comment: @chepner I wanna do that in Perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ways to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$ifile = "ps.txt";

# capture command output
# NOTE: this puts each line in a separate array element -- the newline is _not_
# stripped
@bycat = (`cat $ifile`);

# this strips the newline from all array elements:
chomp(@bycat);

# so would this:
# NOTE: for this type of foreach, if you modify $buf, it also modifies the
# corresponding array element
foreach $buf (@bycat) {
    chomp($buf);
}

# read in all elements line-by-line
open($fin,"<$ifile") or die("unable to open '$ifile' -- $!\n");
while ($buf = <$fin>) {
    chomp($buf);
    push(@byread,$buf);
}
close($fin);

# print the arrays
# NOTE: we are passing the arrays "by-reference"
show("bycat",\@bycat);
show("byread",\@byread);

# show -- dump the array
sub show
# sym -- name of array
# ptr -- reference to array
{
    my($sym,$ptr) = @_;
    my($buf);

    foreach $buf (@$ptr) {
        printf("%s: %s\n",$sym,$buf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cat` to get file contents into a Perl variable, you should use `open` and `<>` in "slurp mode":

```
open my $fh, "<", "ps.txt" or die "Failed to open ps.txt: $!";
local $/;
my $file_contents = <$fh>;
```

Comment: `open` is pretty self explanatory. `<>` returns content of a file, record by record (by default line by line). To return whole file as a single record, the record separator variable - `$/` needs to be unset, which is achieved with `local $/;`.

Comment: The original `bash` code iterates over the contents line-by-line (albeit incorrectly), so leaving `$/` alone and using `my @file_contents = <$fh>;` is probably more correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this is trying to achieve, but this is my answer:

```
my $var = `/bin/cat $0`; # the Perl program itself ;-)
print $var;
```

If you need the lines, `$var` can be split on `$/`.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
my $var = `/bin/cat $0`;
print $var;
my $n = 1;
for my $line ( split( $/, $var ) ){
    print "$n: $line\n";
    $n++;
}
```

Comment: `$0` is the name of the script and _not_ argument zero (e.g. from `foo bar`, `$0` is "foo" and _not_ "bar"). In perl, command line arguments are in a [pre-supplied] array `@ARGV`. So, replace `$0` with `$ARGV[0]`

Comment: @CraigEstey  I was using the Perl program itself for testing :-) But I've should have made that clear.

Comment: Yep. I didn't "grok" that and I've been doing perl for 20+. The comment "fixes" things.